# My apple headphones with Mic used to work fine on windows 10, but stopped working?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

So, I have a mobile phone headphones which work perfectly fine with the mobile phone on skype. They used to work fine with skype on desktop too. But now all of a sudden they stopped working with desktop, but they still work fine with mobile. I have tried updating drivers, changing boost level, giving permissions to the mic for skype. Please help me with the situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to Windows 10 v. 1903, there are [known Bluetooth issues](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2019/08/24/microsoft-windows-10-update-problem-bluetooth-warning-upgrade-windows-10/#1da9c64367f2). To find out, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `winver`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can try to fix it with [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4518538/bluetooth-speakers-do-not-work-after-update-4505903-is-installed) or roll back to a more fully debugged version of Windows.